# How can I build graph (using Graphx) from Spark Dataframe?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, spark-graphx

I have already created a Spark DataFrame in order to build graph by Graphx which is Spark's API and accepts Spark Dataframe format. So, now I have such a data,

```
+--------------------+----------------+------+
|           hotel_url|          author|rating|
+--------------------+----------------+------+
|Hotel_Review-g194...|    violettaf340|     5|
|Hotel_Review-g194...|       Lagaiuzza|     5|
|Hotel_Review-g194...|      ashleyn763|     5|
|Hotel_Review-g194...|     DavideMauro|     5|
|Hotel_Review-g194...|        Alemma11|     4|
|Hotel_Review-g194...|       ladispoli|     4|
|Hotel_Review-g303...|       LiliT0URS|     3|
|Hotel_Review-g303...|     Amandainldn|     4|
|Hotel_Review-g303...|TwoMonkeysTravel|     5|
|Hotel_Review-g303...|     BiancaB3358|     4|
|Hotel_Review-g303...|    Brett-Sweden|     4|
|Hotel_Review-g303...|      analuizade|     5|
|Hotel_Review-g303...|          heckfy|     5|
|Hotel_Review-g303...|  MatheusMedrado|     3|
|Hotel_Review-g303...|TwoMonkeysTravel|     5|
|Hotel_Review-g303...|          SaStar|     4|
|Hotel_Review-g303...|   chrisbG2838DY|     4|
|Hotel_Review-g303...|        virninha|     5|
|Hotel_Review-g303...|    AugustusC_13|     5|
|Hotel_Review-g303...|         AnnaMir|     5|
+--------------------+----------------+------+
```

and I would like to ask you that how to create a graph which has [ (Node: hotel_url) --- (weight: rating) --- (Node: author)] such type of relationship from the Spark Dataframe?

You can also understand desired relationship from the given figure.

[image: Graph Figure]

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.graphx.Edge
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.graphx.Graph
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.graphx._
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import spark.implicits._

val data = List(
  ("Hotel_Review-g194...", "violettaf340", 5),
  ("Hotel_Review-g194...", "Lagaiuzza", 5),
  ("Hotel_Review-g194...", "ashleyn763", 5),
  ("Hotel_Review-g194...", "DavideMauro", 5),
  ("Hotel_Review-g194...", "Alemma11", 4),
  ("Hotel_Review-g194...", "ladispoli", 4),
  ("Hotel_Review-g303...", "LiliT0URS", 3),
  ("Hotel_Review-g303...", "Amandainldn", 4),
  ("Hotel_Review-g303...", "TwoMonkeysTravel", 5),
  ("Hotel_Review-g303...", "BiancaB3358", 4),
  ("Hotel_Review-g303...", "Brett-Sweden", 4),
  ("Hotel_Review-g303...", "analuizade", 5),
  ("Hotel_Review-g303...", "heckfy", 5),
  ("Hotel_Review-g303...", "MatheusMedrado", 3),
  ("Hotel_Review-g303...", "TwoMonkeysTravel", 5),
  ("Hotel_Review-g303...", "SaStar", 4),
  ("Hotel_Review-g303...", "chrisbG2838DY", 4),
  ("Hotel_Review-g303...", "virninha", 5),
  ("Hotel_Review-g303...", "AugustusC_13", 5),
  ("Hotel_Review-g303...", "AnnaMir", 5)
).toDF("hotel_url", "author", "rating")

val vertices: RDD[(VertexId, String)] = data
  .select(explode(array(col("hotel_url"), col("author"))))
  .dropDuplicates()
  .rdd
  .map(_.getAs[String](0))
  .zipWithIndex
  .map(_.swap)

val vertDF = vertices.toDF("id", "node")

val edges = data
  .join(vertDF, data.col("hotel_url") === vertDF("node"))
  .select('author, 'rating.cast(StringType), 'id as 'idS)
  .join(vertDF, data("author") === vertDF("node"))
  .rdd
  .map(row =>
    Edge(
      row.getAs[Long]("idS"),
      row.getAs[Long]("id"),
      "rating: " + row.getAs[String]("rating")
    )
  )

val graph = Graph(vertices, edges)

graph.vertices.foreach(println _)
//    (2,Amandainldn)
//    (7,heckfy)
//    (5,DavideMauro)
//    (0,MatheusMedrado)
//    (4,ashleyn763)
//    (1,LiliT0URS)
//    (3,chrisbG2838DY)
//    (9,Brett-Sweden)
//    (11,virninha)
//    (12,BiancaB3358)
//    (16,AnnaMir)
//    (10,TwoMonkeysTravel)
//    (6,SaStar)
//    (17,AugustusC_13)
//    (19,ladispoli)
//    (20,Alemma11)
//    (14,analuizade)
//    (8,Lagaiuzza)
//    (18,violettaf340)
//    (15,Hotel_Review-g194...)
//    (13,Hotel_Review-g303...)

graph.edges.foreach(println(_))
//    Edge(13,0,rating: 3)
//    Edge(13,1,rating: 3)
//    Edge(13,3,rating: 4)
//    Edge(15,4,rating: 5)
//    Edge(13,2,rating: 4)
//    Edge(13,12,rating: 4)
//    Edge(13,10,rating: 5)
//    Edge(13,10,rating: 5)
//    Edge(15,8,rating: 5)
//    Edge(15,5,rating: 5)
//    Edge(13,9,rating: 4)
//    Edge(13,6,rating: 4)
//    Edge(13,11,rating: 5)
//    Edge(15,18,rating: 5)
//    Edge(13,14,rating: 5)
//    Edge(13,16,rating: 5)
//    Edge(15,19,rating: 4)
//    Edge(13,17,rating: 5)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually I have 50K rows in the dataset, SparkDataframe.show() describes maximum 20 rows in the shell. I would like to have solution which is able to handle whole dataset instead of creating and typing lists one by one.

Comment: df.show(<count rows to show>, true)

Comment: Actually I have 50K - try use.